# Android SSL certificate cloudflare https port

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpclient, cloudflare

I am making a socket factory on **HttpClient** to connect my SSL server
i have certificate my Scheme! by this code:

```
schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
```

but still making error for me!

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

*** i am using cloudflare SSL service**

i thing it may because cloudflare has a different SSL port